# Lost on how to append numpy vectors/matrices/arrays

Tags: python, numpy, linear-programming

I'm currently trying to build a practice linear parameter estimation python program using numpy but I've never written in python before and I'm very loose with numpy. I have a series of x,y data points that I want to loop over and build a new vector with that is a 5x1 vector containing only the y values.

Here is what I have so far that isn't working:

```
def data_loader():
    ## edit to have an i/o feature for retrieving data points later ##
    data_points = np.array([[1,5.7],[2,19.2],[3,37.8],[4,67.3],[5,86.4]])
    return data_points

def build_b(data_points):
    b = np.empty((0,1), int)
    for x in data_points:
        for y in x:
            b = np.append(y, axis=0)
    return b
```

In addition I would also like to eventually have a user input for data points but that is down the road I guess.

Comment: Learn python first, then learn numpy. So first a python tutorial, then a numpy one.

Comment: `b = np.append(y, axis=0)` - how much time did you spend reading `np.append` docs?  It is not a list append clone; and is slower when it does work.   That `build_b` loop looks like you have used, or at least read about, a list append loop.  Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch just the Y values, use `data_points[:,1]`.  That says "use all rows, but only element 1 (counting from 0) of the rows".

That's a 5-element vector.  Not sure why you're expecting (3,1).

Comment: I meant to say 5 not 3. So I would just use data_points[:,1] in the for each statement?

Comment: You would not use a `for` statement at all.  `data_points[:,1]` returns to you a 5-element array.  That's the only statement you need.  The BIG advantage of numpy is that you work with whole arrays, or columns, or rows at a time.  No looping.